# Kubernetes ingress path pointing to multiple paths in a single service

Tags: vue.js, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a simple application in Vue with two pages. I run it as a single service in a single pod in Kubernetes. The pages I have are `/` and `/view`. From `/` there is a button I click on to move to `/view` and vice versa.
The problem I'm facing is that if I refresh the page while on `/view` page I get `502 Bad Gateway` error.
My Vue app looks like this:

```
<template>
<header class="header">
      <div class="Title">Title</div>
      <div class="header-buttons">
        <router-link to="/" class="header-button">Upload</router-link>
        <router-link to="/view" class="header-button">View</router-link>
      </div>
    </header>
  <div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then my router config looks like this:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'; 
import App from './App.vue';
import Home from './Home.vue';
import View from './View.vue';
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'; 

import './assets/main.css'

const app = createApp(App); 

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Home },
  { path: '/view', component: View },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

app.use(router); 

app.mount('#app');
```

In kubernetes I configured ingress like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nsx
    ncp/http-redirect: "True"
    ncp/use-regex: "True"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: frontend
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          service:
            name: frontend
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /view
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - secretName: ingress-cert
```

I have tried inverting the order of the paths in ingress but that did not help at all. I am not sure whether this is a Vue issie or K8s.
Any ideas how I can make it work?

Comment: Note that the first route in your Ingress resource **already** matches `/view`. Moreover, you should switch to the Prefix type and just route the / prefix to your container. Other than that, 502 bad gateway is generated by your ingress controller, not your Vue server.